# Kotlin Playground – Variable 'mainProperty' initializer is redundant

Tags: kotlin

I'm testing `Any` type in Kotlin Playground:

```
fun main() {
    
    var mainProperty: Any? = 5.0
    
    mainProperty = "Hello, Kotlin!"

    println(mainProperty)
}
```

Why when I assign a new value to property of type `Any`, playground prints result but give me the following message?

```
// Variable 'mainProperty' initializer is redundant
```

[image]

Comment: it's redundant because you overwrite it without accessing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler notices that you never used the **5.0** value before reassigning the variable, so it warns you about that.

If you insert a print statement between reassignments, the warning will go away:

```
fun main() {
    
    var mainProperty: Any? = 5.0
    
    println(mainProperty)
    
    mainProperty = "Hello, Kotlin!"

    println(mainProperty)
}
```

If you do this on an IDE like Intellij and follow the recommendations it gives, the simplified code will be something like:

```
fun main() {

    val mainProperty: Any?

    mainProperty = "Hello, Kotlin!"

    println(mainProperty)
}
```